# How to integrate in 2D, along the locus of a line.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If I have a 2D continuous and differentiable function (f(x,y)) how do I evaluate the definite integral of f with respect to x and y along the line L between an arbitrary start (x1, y1) and end point (x2, y2) in the 2D space?

Comment: $ax+by+c=0$ is a plane, not a line. This changes the nature of your question, so you may want to rephrase accordingly.

Comment: You are quite right! Reworded accordingly.

Comment: Keep in mind that in order for such an integral to be possible, $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ must be on the intersection of $L$ and $f(x,y)$.

Comment: Yes, I am defining L to be line defined between points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) and that f(x,y) is continuous and differentiable for all x, y.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an integral over a line segment L:

$$\int_Lf(x,y)dS$$

If the line defined by parametric equations $\langle{x(t)},y(t)\rangle$, the integral can be solved as follows:

$$\int_Lf(x,y)dS=\int_a^bf(x(t),y(t))\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}dt$$

Where $(x_1,y_1)=(x(a),y(a))$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(x(b),y(b))$.

Comment: My apologies, I supplied a planar equation in my question, and really want the integral along an arbitrary line. Is there a modified version of your answer that would work in that case.

Comment: @AndrewS. Ok got it. See my edit.